# Route Url doesn't reflect avoid highway option

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I got this link which i generate from code. It succefully shows route:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=&destination=52.229675,21.012230&travelmode=driving&dir_action=navigate
```

I read that if i want to include avoid highways i would need to add `dirflg=h` which i did as shown below:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=&destination=52.229675,21.012230&travelmode=driving&dir_action=navigate&dirflg=h,t
```

Nevertheles link shows route same as first link and on the website with route i see `avoid highways` option is not marked. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the comma t at end of URL?

Comment: @jdweng t seems to be parameter for "tools" - nevertheless i removed that t parameter and it still not working

Comment: If the request wasn't formatted properly you would get an error number in the response which is normally 200 OK.  Using a sniffer would verify that you are getting the 200 OK.  But you are not getting an exception (or error) so the server is accepting the request.  Try : &avoid=highways (see : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/overview#restrictions)

Comment: @jdweng not working. I works as it would not be that parameter given.

Comment: it should work.  the the highway maybe isn't a highway.

Comment: @jdweng yes but when i manually check on website option avoid highways it shows diffrent route... Can you give two working links - with avoid and without avoid to see whether it works?

Comment: What are the two URLs with different routes?  The URL contains the parameters.  You should get same results in API as browser with same parameters.

Comment: @jdweng I ment could you give route url example that works with your avoid highway so when i remove that parameter diffrent route will be shown, because from my end when i take url and put &avoid=highways at the end it doesn't make any diffrence in route calculation. I checked few diffrent routes where there are highways.

Comment: Do your  tests match the routes using the Google Webpage/API?  The best way of debugging is to get the URL from Google Webpage(or API) and then run same test in c# with same URL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220431/discussion-between-arie-and-jdweng).

Comment: Dont get the point. As in question i got valid link which works. When i add your suggestion means: &avoid=highways at the end of link it doesn't reflect that. I;ve tested with many diffrent examples and no one is working as expected. P.S I asked you to talk in chat.

Comment: It appears that you are using the [Directions mode of the Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started#forming-the-directions-url). As you can see on this link, the parameter `dirflg` is not really documented.

There is an existing feature request on the Issue Tracker ([Issue 80036567](https://issuetracker.google.com/80036567)) to avoid `tollroads`. You could try adding a comment on the issue and indicate the specific feature (Ex. highway) that you wanted to avoid and star the issue. This will subscribe you to receive technical updates on the feature request.

Comment: @annkylah So hold on you mean i can just create link with origin, destination, waypoints and navigation mode as i provided in first example link and nothing else? P.S My target is to show the route it dont need to be even in navigation mode.

Comment: Well, yes, the only documented parameter for Directions - Maps URLs are those you mentioned and some other optional parameters. Use of other undocumented parameters  does not have a defined behavior, so I guess we should not expect that specifying `dirflg=h` on your Maps URL request would return a route that would avoid the highways... This is why I recommended that you leave a comment and "star" the existing FR to send your feedback to the appropriate team.

Comment: @annkylah So how could i construct such url? In my application i need to generate url based on cordinates and with avoid highways. Is there any possibility? P.S I got API key if need. PS.2 : WHere is this star on tracker?

Comment: I don't know any other workarounds to achieve your use case by using the Maps URLs - Universal cross-platform syntax. Avoiding highways seems to be supported on the Google Maps Intents for Android - [Turn-by-turn navigation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#search_for_a_location) though. Please check if this would fit your use case. 

As for starring the issue, you should be able to find it next to the issue title. Here's how: https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#subscribing_by_starring_an_issue

Comment: If you want to build your own map on your implementation instead of redirecting users on Google Maps app, this is possible by using [Maps JavaScript API and the Directions Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions). Avoiding highways via `avoidHighways` parameter is supported by the Directions service.